# Using NGRX in a Route Resolver

Tags: rxjs, angular6, ngrx

I am using Angular 6.
I am also using NGRX Store.
I am using a route guard to make sure the user is logged in to the application.
I then use a resolver to get the initial user profile, then place it in the NGRX store.

I am new to NGRX and I am not sure if this is the correct way to write the resolver.

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
     return this.loginService.getLoginData()
        .pipe(
            map((result:UserData) => { 
                this.store.dispatch(new userActions.SetLoginData(result)); 
                this.loginService.getDropdownData(
                    result.userId, 
                    result.countryCode,
                ).subscribe( data => { 
                    this.store.dispatch(new userActions.SetDropdownData(data));
                })
            })
        )
}
```

I am also not sure if this is the correct way to do the RXJS.

any suggestions,
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to point you to [Preloading ngrx/store with Route Guards](https://toddmotto.com/preloading-ngrx-store-route-guards), an article of Todd Motto which explains it really well.

There is also an example of the guard in the [NgRx example app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/guards/book-exists.guard.ts)

```
@Injectable()
export class CoursesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private store: Store<CoursesState>) {}

  getFromStoreOrAPI(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store
      .select(getCoursesState)
      .do((data: any) => {
        if (!data.courses.length) {
          this.store.dispatch(new Courses.CoursesGet());
        }
      })
      .filter((data: any) => data.courses.length)
      .take(1);
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.getFromStoreOrAPI()
      .switchMap(() => of(true))
      .catch(() => of(false));
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why this wouldn't be part of a route resolver? That feels the more natural place rather than a canActivate.

Comment: Because routeResolver is to resolve and "give" data to the component. For me, this is the job of NgRx, canActivate can help to populate the store

Comment: But "resolving" the data here is done in the canActivate, it doesn't give the data to the component, but it does actually request it. I feel like canActivate should be just a route guard, and the resolver should handle resolving (and giving)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think it would make sense to seperate the authentication check and the data resolution into separate classes. For authentication it makes more sense to use a `CanActivate` guard. See: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

With this out of the way your resolver can focus on only getting the data that is actually required. Here you need to be aware that if you return an observable in your resolver, the observable needs to complete in order for the resolver to complete. The problem is that if you select something from the store, the resulting observable never completes, hence your resolver will never finish resolving your data. You can work around this fact by using the `first()` or `take(1)` operator. timdeschryvers answer has a nice example on how to accomplish that.